# Automate tests in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate (using TFS)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, testing, automated-tests

I have a series of web tests that I have created with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, each of them run all fine, but now I need those test to run once a week automatically.

I have read that "there's a possible way to do it via TFS" but I can't load even one test on TFS...

I'm all ears if anyone can share a link of "hey this is how it should be done"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have TFS available (you weren't clear), then you can use scheduling to set up these sorts of automated runs. There's a [good article on MSDN showing how to do this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182465).

If you don't have TFS then you can run your tests via the command line ([MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182486)) with a scheduler job.

A much better solution, though, would be to use something like Hudson/Jenkins, Team City, or some other free/cheap build server. The implementation (How-To) for each of those varies, but scads of folks use Team City and it's fairly simple to set up. (Free for small teams, too.)

Comment: Well, "it's not helping" doesn't give a lot of information on what's lacking... :) That is a long article about configuring your tests and environment to get an automated build deployed in the TFS environment. Yes, there's a lot of moving parts.